# Flutter, 2 animation controllers result in error

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I need to have 2 animation controllers, because one will play forever and another will play only once.

But for some reason, when initializing second animation controller app crashes.

Here's the code:

```
class _GlassTypeState extends State<GlassType>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _pulsateTween;

  AnimationController _opacityController;
  Animation _opacityTween;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //WORKS Perfectly
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    );
    _pulsateTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.white24, end: Colors.white)
        .animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.repeat(reverse: true);     
    //----

    _opacityController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    ); //ERROR happens here, if I comment this out no errors.

    // _opacityTween = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_opacityController);
    // _opacityController.forward();
  }
```

Flutter's errors are usually useless, but anyways:

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.

type 'RenderErrorBox' is not a subtype of type 'RenderSemanticsGestureHandler' in type cast
```

For more context, I have one widget `AnimatedBuilder()` widget rendered in the `build` method, this widget uses `_pulsateTween` tween and works fine.

I know this, because I've tried rendering empty `Container()`, but it still crashed when creating 2nd `AnimationController`.

*PS: If this works fine for you, please inform me and I will make a bug report on github.*

Comment: You have multiple AnimationControllers and you're using ```SingleTickerProviderStateMixin```. The ```SingleTickerProviderStateMixin``` should be used with one animation controller only. Replace it with ```TickerProviderStateMixin``` and it should work.

Comment: @danypata Thanks, Could you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help other users in the future:

`SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` should be used only when there is a **single** `AnimationController`.

If there are multiple `AnimationController` instances in the same state, then `TickerProviderStateMixin` should be used.